# Combining/arranging multiple cells of different data frames/files in R

Tags: java, r, loops, raster

I have weather data (max temp) of UK in Ascii text format for 10 years. Each text file contain weather data one month for different locations. Data frame 1 to 12 as January to December for each year so 12 months x 10 years = 120 files / data frames in following format:

Data Frame 1 [Year 1 January]:
24.65 23.44 22.55 21.33 23.22 ....... n

Data Frame 2 [Year 1 February]
16.81 21.13 14.37 11.17 22.29 ....... n

**Data Frame 3 to 12 [Year 1 March to December] ...........**

Data Frame 13 [Year 2 January]
11.10 10.89 11.71 16.78 12.11 ....... n

Data Frame 14 [Year 2 February]
14.43 17.33 20.51 18.54 14.62 ....... n

i want to generate a code that read all text files and then pick 1st value of data frame 1 and then 1st value of data frame 2 and so on ....

At the end, data frame should look like this:

Location   Year    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May ........ December
Location 1 Year 1: 24.65 16.81  x    x      x  .........  x
Location 1 Year 2: 11.10 14.43  x    x      x  .........  x
.
.
Location 1 Year 10: x     x     x    x      x  .........  x
Location 2 Year 1: 23.44 21.13  x    x      x  .........  x
Location 2 Year 2: 10.89 17.33  x    x      x  .........  x
.
.
Location n Year 10: x     x      x    x      x  .........  x

Then to Save this new data frame into Ascii text.

Can anyone help please? Quite complicated to to use any function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOFvC.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could improve your question by reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523).

Comment: @Anonymouscoward please check this image to understand my question as i can see the question typed was different then showing here. Here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOFvC.jpg